# Remesh modifier bug?

Tags: modifiers

Following along this tutorial :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=45&v=nkaHXlFS0c8

I get this weird shape; although it's pretty simple.

Any idea why ? is this a Bug ?

Without the modifier

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe some rotation? You should put a picture of the mesh without the modifier.

Comment: rotation ? mmmh i edited the post

Comment: Yes I mean is something is not along the world axis, that could lead to this kind of result.

Comment: oh ok... this may be the scale parameter in the remesh. Try to tune it.